# Print text with clickable link in console or terminal in Perl

Tags: perl

We have a program written in Perl that display output in a console or terminal. I have to add a new output that should contain clickable links. I am new to Perl so need some help on this.

The output should look like this:

Please refer to the [FAQ](http://example.org) for help. For further assistance raise a ticket to our [help Desk](http://example.org)

Comment: That's most likely not possible. If it's a normal terminal application, there is no clicking. A regular URL might be turned into a clickable thing by your terminal emulator, but that's the best you can get, and your program cannot influence that anyway. I'd push back on that requirement and explain to them how they want the impossible.

Comment: There's one detail I left out: The program is called by a Jenkins job and the output is displayed in Jenkins console log. Looking at the log, I do see some links but those links are variables and they are displayed as http://link.com While in my case it would be a static link with a word pointing to the link itself.

Comment: Are you looking at the Jenkins console in a web browser?

Comment: Not possible to rename the link according to this duplicate. You can always say _Please refer to the FAQ (http://example.org/faq) for help. For further assistance raise a ticket to our help desk (http://example.org/help)._ and the URLs will become clickable links. That's a good middle way. An alternative would be _... the FAQ at http://example.org/faq. ..._